Transferred files on Flash Drives/External Drives become unreadable past a certain point
I'm transferring all sorts of files from images to videos to Zip Files. A mix of small and large files, some exceeding 4gb so I've formatted my External Drives to NTFS and Default Memory Allocation.
Just bought a brand new HP Flash Drive from the retail store that has 500gb storage. The first 30gb worth of files transferred with no issue. Files can be read on different devices (Smart TV, PC) no problem. However at some point, my most recent transfers become unreadable or possibly corrupted. Zip files turn out an error when unzipping, and video, music and image files are unreadable/unsupported.
Here's a specific example of this issue. I've transferred 10 video files in succession. Up to the 7th file are fully readable and okay, but the 8th video cuts off halfway and 9 and 10 are also unreadable.
I've gone through 2 External Hard drives before purchasing this latest Flash Drive. I thought my oldest Hard drive was just broken, so I bought another Hard Drive online and it's the same Issue and thought I purchased a faulty drive (despite checking the integrity/health of the drive turning out ok).
This can't be a coincidence anymore.
Attempting to reformat and repair these drives, I'm still met with the same issue. First few gigabytes worth of Files are fine and fully readable, but at some point the transferred files no longer are.
I feel there is something i'm misunderstanding about these External Storage Devices. I've nowhere reached the Maximum storage limit on any of these devices, yet I can't seem to fill them up with no issue. Why is this? and What can I do to avoid or fix these issues?

This really really really looks like a fake USB drive. See this video.

What form factor – USB stick or full-size portable USB drive? It smells like one of those "32GB flash with 500GB written on it" fake USB sticks that used to be common.

It's possible. I'll have to check with that test.
I can't believe I've got three Drives bought at different times and from different sources all be fakes...

Although it probably won't help, I agree with the others that it points to being a fake, you should tell us what kind of system this is running on. I hope it's not some old version of WinNT. I would also test it on another system.

What operating system? If Windows, have you uses robocopy? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy

Please provide the brand and model of the drives.  How did you format the drives?  What properties did you select when formatting?
